# How can I alphabetize the first column of a .csv file in C?

Tags: c, csv, file, sorting

I have a .csv file. Let's say the data is like this:

```
Location 1,Location 2,Price,Rooms,Bathrooms,CarParks,Type,Area,Furnish
Upper-East-Side,New-York,310000,3,2,0,Built-up,1000,Partly
West-Village,New-York,278000,2,2,0,Built-up,1000,Partly
Theater-District,New-York,688000,3,2,0,Built-up,1000,Partly
```

Expected output (alphabetized):

```
Theater-District
Upper-East-Side
West-Village
```

How can I only show and alphabetize the first column (Location 1) of the file while also skipping the header?

This is currently my code but it's still in a "read and display" form.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fh;
  
  fh = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  
  if (fh != NULL)
  {
    int line_number = 0;
    char c;
    while ( (c = fgetc(fh)) != EOF )
    {
        if(line_number > 0 || c == '\n'){
            putchar(c);
        }
        if(c == '\n'){
            line_number++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fh);
  
  } else printf("Error opening file.\n");
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the whole line as input: make yourself a helper function to do that. Allocate the lines in an array. Sort the array withe qsort and strcmp

Comment: Here is the shell one-liner: `(read -r header; printf "%s\n" "$header"; sort -k1 -t,) < unsorted.csv > sorted.csv`.  csvkit has a `csvsort` command.

Comment: csv is not a well defined format, if this isn't homework, at least use a library instead of writing csv parser.

Comment: If you want sort and projection it's even easer: `tail +2 unsorted.csv | cut -d, -f1 | sort > sorted.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

csv is not a well defined format so I suggest you use an existing csv library instead of parsing the data yourself.  For instance, this will not work if the first field has any embedded commas.  It relies on scanf() to allocate the line, and resizes the `lines` array as needed.  This means there are no arbitrary limits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int strcmp2(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp((const char *) a, (const char *) b);
}

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("unsorted.csv", "r");
    if(!f) return 1;

    char **lines = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    for(;; n++) {
        char *location1;
        int rv = fscanf(f, "%m[^,]%*[^\n]\n", &location1);
        if(rv != 1) break;
        char **tmp = realloc(lines, (n + 1) * sizeof *tmp);
        if(!tmp) return 1;
        lines = tmp;
        tmp[n] = location1;
    }
    fclose(f);

    free(lines[0]); // header
    qsort(&lines[1], n - 1, sizeof *lines, strcmp2);
    for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
        free(lines[i]);
    }
    free(lines);
}
```

It produces the expected output:

```
Theater-District
Upper-East-Side
West-Village
```

Comment: To sort over the first field only... no need to parse individual fields from the record.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I am only extracting the first field.  To sort, you technically have to parse the data although in practice you may be able to just sort the line as it's the first field in this case.  If you don't care about the extra memory usage just use `fgets()` to read lines as your solution does.

Comment: UV for the magic `%ms` field specifier. A good solution. I thought no one had noticed this question...

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got an "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char**' [-fpermissive]" error from the realloc line. I already tried changing the compiler to C instead of C++. I'm using Dev-C++ as my IDE.

Comment: @Juju Double check that you wrote it exactly as I did (I have no warnings).  Specifically the `lines` declaration and the `realloc()` line.  C++ requires a cast while you don't want one with C.  C and C++ are two different languages, and you tagged this C.  If you can't figure it it out post a new question with a [mre].  Make sure you tag it with your IDE as I don't think it's a code issue (but you're compiling this as a C++).

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming some hard limits on line length and CSV file record count, we can just use arrays.

To read a record, just use `fgets()`. Add each line of text to the array using the usual method.

We use a simple string search and truncate to isolate the first field. (Assuming no fancy stuff like double-quoted fields. I assume you are doing homework.)

To sort everything *except* the CSV header record, use `qsort()` with a little additional mathematics.

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define unused(x) (void)(x)

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_RECORD_COUNT 100

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  unused( argc );

  char records[MAX_RECORD_COUNT][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
  size_t record_count = 0;
  
  const char * filename = argv[1];
  if (!filename) return 1;

  // Read our records from file
  FILE * f = fopen( filename, "r" );
  if (!f) return 1;

  while ((record_count < MAX_RECORD_COUNT)
      and fgets( records[record_count], MAX_LINE_LENGTH, f ))
    record_count += 1;

  fclose( f );
  
  // Truncate the strings to just the first field
  for (size_t n = 0;  n < record_count;  n++)
  {
    char * p = strchr( records[n], ',' );
    if (p) *p = '\0';
  }
  
  // Sort everything but the header
  if (record_count > 2)  // must exist at least two records + header
    qsort( records+1, record_count-1, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, 
      (int (*)( const void *, const void * ))strcmp );
  
  // Print everything but the header
  for (size_t n = 1;  n < record_count;  n++)
    printf( "%s\n", records[n] );
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, gcc gave me warning for using strcmp directly in qsort() which is why I did the wrapper with the appropriate casts.  If you don't know the '&' is not required.

Comment: Dangit, you’re right. (I only compiled with MSVC.) This is one of the few occasions that you _could_ just use `strcmp()` directly. Shame it complains. (I crank my warnings _waaay_ up, and some compiler, somewhere, complains if I leave the `&` off.)

Comment: I was curious... "a function designator with type “function returning type” is converted to an expression that has type “pointer to function returning type” (6.3.2.1).

Comment: I suggest you combine your snippets into a program.  The benefit of simpler (and faster) code when using preallocated automatic storage arrays get lost in the literate programming style.  Also, leave the edit to the revision history, and just present your current best solution.

Comment: Well, it’s taken me a moment to run through them all, and I can’t get one to complain. I’d swear something spewed stuff at me about it just recently, but maybe I’m just going senile.